# How to Play Single Audio for Different Video Qualities in Swift AVPlayer using HLS (m3u8)?

Tags: swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm working on a video streaming app in Swift that utilizes HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) with multiple video qualities. I'm using the AVPlayer framework to play the videos. The master m3u8 file specifies different video qualities along with audio options. However, I'm facing challenges in configuring the AVPlayer to play the appropriate audio stream for each video quality.

Here's an excerpt from my master m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U

#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="audio/audio.m3u8",GROUP-ID="audio",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="ENGLISH",AUTOSELECT=YES,CHANNELS="2"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=745697,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=508245,CODECS="avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=854x480,FRAME-RATE=25.000,VIDEO-RANGE=SDR,AUDIO="audio",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
480p/22534041-c4c5-4b5b-be4e-e7035e4ffdb6.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=961804,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=663000,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=25.000,VIDEO-RANGE=SDR,AUDIO="audio",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
720p/04b4f73f-3f43-4c88-895f-931c22564e3d.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=534811,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=389186,CODECS="avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360,FRAME-RATE=25.000,VIDEO-RANGE=SDR,AUDIO="audio",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
360p/df767a2b-833a-4772-94cd-099e8ccf48e4.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2914202,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2041333,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,FRAME-RATE=25.000,VIDEO-RANGE=SDR,AUDIO="audio",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
1080p/f0c10df4-df65-4800-9e45-ff684357d4d7.m3u8
```

I need guidance on how to configure the AVPlayer in Swift to ensure that the appropriate audio stream is played along with the selected video quality. Should I be handling this programmatically by monitoring user quality selection and then updating the AVPlayer's audio track, or is there a more automated way to achieve this integration between video quality and audio selection?

Answer (score 0):

Note:Please replace the VideoQuality enum cases and URLs with your actual URLs and quality definitions.

```
import AVFoundation
    
    // This is just an example enum representing video quality levels
    enum VideoQuality: String {
        case sd480p
        case hd720p
        case hd1080p
        
        var playlistURL: String {
            return "\(rawValue)/playlist.m3u8"
        }
    }
    
    // This mapping relates video quality to its associated audio group ID
    var qualityToAudioMapping: [VideoQuality: String] = [
        .sd480p: "audio",
        .hd720p: "audio",
        .hd1080p: "audio"
    ]
    
    // User selects a video quality
    let selectedQuality: VideoQuality = .hd720p
    
    // Get the corresponding audio group ID
    guard let audioGroupID = qualityToAudioMapping[selectedQuality] else {
        fatalError("No audio group associated with the selected quality")
    }
    
    // Create AVPlayerItem for the selected video quality
    let videoURL = URL(string: selectedQuality.playlistURL)!
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL)
    
    // Select the appropriate audio track
    if let audioSelectionGroup = playerItem.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: .audible) {
        for option in audioSelectionGroup.options {
            if option.identifier?.rawValue == audioGroupID {
                playerItem.select(option, in: audioSelectionGroup)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Create AVPlayer with the configured AVPlayerItem
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    
    // Present or play the player as needed
    // For example, using AVPlayerViewController
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
```

Comment: can you give an example with [http://95.85.127.129:8080/master.m3u8](http://95.85.127.129:8080/master.m3u8) with this hls file? @vaibhav sharma